# Why is app engine project not calling unittest.TestCase.tearDown()?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-unittest

I'm trying to setup test for the App Engine python tutorial.
It seems that the unittest.tearDown() is not being called because the print statement I put in the tearDown method is not displayed.

The unittest.TestCase.setUp() is being called, so why is the tearDown() not called?

```
import sys, os, subprocess, time, unittest, shlex     
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine")   
sys.path.append('/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/')     
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/yaml/lib")      
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2")      
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/django-1.5")      
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/cherrypy")      
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/concurrent")      
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/docker")      
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/requests")      
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/websocket")      
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib")      
sys.path.append("/usr/local/google_appengine/lib/antlr3")      

from selenium import webdriver      
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  

from google.appengine.api import memcache, apiproxy_stub, apiproxy_stub_map       
from google.appengine.ext import testbed      
from google.appengine.datastore import datastore_stub_util       
from google.appengine.tools.devappserver2 import devappserver2      
from guestbook import Author, Greeting    
from google.appengine.api import users  
from google.appengine.ext import ndb  


class NewVisitorTest(unittest.TestCase):      
    # enable the datastore stub  
    nosegae_datastore_v3 = True  
    nosegae_datastore_v3_kwargs = {  
        'datastore_file': '/tmp/nosegae.sqlite3',  
        'use_sqlite': True  
    }  

    def setUp(self):      
        self.testbed = testbed.Testbed()  
        self.testbed.setup_env(app_id='guestbook')      
        self.testbed.activate()        
        self.datastore_stub = apiproxy_stub_map.apiproxy.GetStub('datastore_v3')    
        ndb.get_context().clear_cache()    
        APP_CONFIGS = ['app.yaml']      

    def tearDown(self):   
        print("#####################functional_tests.teardown called")  
        self.testbed.deactivate()   
        # I put a print statement into testbed.deactivate and it's not showing up.     
        ndb.get_context().clear_cache()    

    def loginUser(self, email="elonMusk@example.com", id='888', is_admin=False):  
        self.testbed.setup_env(  
            user_email=email,  
            user_id=id,  
            user_is_admin='1' if is_admin else '0',  
            overwrite=True  
        )  
        self.testbed.init_user_stub()  

    def test_guest_can_submit_new_greeting_and_author(self):  

         #self.browser.get('http://localhost:8080')  
         self.loginUser()  
         greetings = Greeting.query(Greeting.author.email=='elonMusk@example.com').get()  
         pprint.pprint(greetings)  
         assert(Greeting.query(Greeting.author.email=='elonMusk@example.com').get()
self.assertEqual(1, len(Greeting.query().fetch(10)))  

    def test_entity_saves(self):  
         self.loginUser()              
         entity_key = Greeting(content="Test Value",   
                           author = Author(  
                                    identity=users.get_current_user().user_id(),  
                                    email=users.get_current_user().email())  
                           ).put()  
         print(entity_key)  
         self.assertIsNotNone(entity_key.id())    
         #self.assertNotNone(entity.key.id())
```

Here is the output from the tests:

nosetests -v --with-gae

```
test_entity_saves (functional_tests.NewVisitorTest) ... ok  
test_guest_can_submit_new_greeting_and_author (functional_tests.NewVisitorTest) ... FAIL  

======================================================================  
FAIL: test_guest_can_submit_new_greeting_and_author (functional_tests.NewVisitorTest)  
----------------------------------------------------------------------  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/Users/Bryan/work/GoogleAppEngine/guestbook/functional_tests.py", line 124, in test_guest_can_submit_new_greeting_and_author  
    self.assertEqual(1, len(Greeting.query().fetch(10)))  
AssertionError: 1 != 10  
-------------------- >> begin captured stdout << ---------------------  
#*#**#*#*#*#*#*#*#*#*nosegae.py startTest   
Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 1), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 20, 39, 37, 659460))  

--------------------- >> end captured stdout << ----------------------  
-------------------- >> begin captured logging << --------------------  
root: DEBUG: all_pending: add <Future 106a2e690 created by get_async(query.py:1245) for tasklet _get_async(query.py:1247); pending>  
root: DEBUG: Clearing stale EventLoop instance...  
root: DEBUG:   current = deque([(<bound method AutoBatcher._finished_callback of AutoBatcher(_memcache_del_tasklet)>, (<Future 1069e9650 created by run_queue(context.py:185) for tasklet _memcache_del_tasklet(context.py:1131); result None>, [(<Future 1069e9590 created by add(context.py:211) for AutoBatcher(_memcache_del_tasklet).add(NDB9:ag1kZXZ-Z3Vlc3Rib29rcg8LEghHcmVldGluZxjhXQw, (0, '', None)); result 1>, 'NDB9:ag1kZXZ-Z3Vlc3Rib29rcg8LEghHcmVldGluZxjhXQw')]), {})])  
root: DEBUG: Cleared  
root: DEBUG: nowevent: _help_tasklet_along  
root: DEBUG: Sending None to initial generator _get_async(query.py:1247)  
root: DEBUG: all_pending: add <Future 106a2e850 created by fetch_async(query.py:1223) for tasklet _run_to_list(query.py:971); pending>  
root: DEBUG: initial generator _get_async(query.py:1247) yielded <Future 106a2e850 created by fetch_async(query.py:1223) for tasklet _run_to_list(query.py:971); pending>  
root: DEBUG: <Future 106a2e690 created by get_async(query.py:1245) for tasklet _get_async(query.py:1247) suspended generator _get_async(query.py:1250); pending> is now blocked waiting for <Future 106a2e850 created by fetch_async(query.py:1223) for tasklet _run_to_list(query.py:971); pending>  
root: DEBUG: nowevent: _help_tasklet_along  
root: DEBUG: Sending None to initial generator _run_to_list(query.py:971)  
root: DEBUG: initial generator _run_to_list(query.py:971) yielded <google.appengine.api.apiproxy_stub_map.UserRPC object at 0x106a2ed50>  
root: DEBUG: rpc: datastore_v3.RunQuery  
root: DEBUG: Sending <google.appengine.datastore.datastore_query.Batch object at 0x106a2ec50> to suspended generator _run_to_list(query.py:979)  
root: DEBUG: suspended generator _run_to_list(query.py:979) returned [Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 1), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 20, 39, 37, 659460))]  
root: DEBUG: all_pending: success: remove <Future 106a2e850 created by fetch_async(query.py:1223) for tasklet _run_to_list(query.py:971); result [Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 1), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 20, 39, 37, 659460))]>  
root: DEBUG: nowevent: _on_future_completion  
root: DEBUG: <Future 106a2e690 created by get_async(query.py:1245) for tasklet _get_async(query.py:1247); pending> is no longer blocked waiting for <Future 106a2e850 created by fetch_async(query.py:1223) for tasklet _run_to_list(query.py:971); result [Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 1), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 20, 39, 37, 659460))]>  
root: DEBUG: Sending [Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 1), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 20, 39, 37, 659460))] to suspended generator _get_async(query.py:1250)  
root: DEBUG: suspended generator _get_async(query.py:1250) returned Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 1), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 20, 39, 37, 659460))  
root: DEBUG: all_pending: success: remove <Future 106a2e690 created by get_async(query.py:1245) for tasklet _get_async(query.py:1247); result Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 1), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 20, 39, 37, 659460))>  
root: DEBUG: all_pending: add <Future 1069e9ad0 created by get_async(query.py:1245) for tasklet _get_async(query.py:1247); pending>  
root: DEBUG: nowevent: _help_tasklet_along  
root: DEBUG: Sending None to initial generator _get_async(query.py:1247)  
root: DEBUG: all_pending: add <Future 106a2e650 created by fetch_async(query.py:1223) for tasklet _run_to_list(query.py:971); pending>  
root: DEBUG: initial generator _get_async(query.py:1247) yielded <Future 106a2e650 created by fetch_async(query.py:1223) for tasklet _run_to_list(query.py:971); pending>  
root: DEBUG: <Future 1069e9ad0 created by get_async(query.py:1245) for tasklet _get_async(query.py:1247) suspended generator _get_async(query.py:1250); pending> is now blocked waiting for <Future 106a2e650 created by fetch_async(query.py:1223) for tasklet _run_to_list(query.py:971); pending>  
root: DEBUG: nowevent: _help_tasklet_along  
root: DEBUG: Sending None to initial generator _run_to_list(query.py:971)  
root: DEBUG: initial generator _run_to_list(query.py:971) yielded <google.appengine.api.apiproxy_stub_map.UserRPC object at 0x106a2ee50>  
root: DEBUG: rpc: datastore_v3.RunQuery  
root: DEBUG: Sending <google.appengine.datastore.datastore_query.Batch object at 0x106a2ee10> to suspended generator _run_to_list(query.py:979)  
root: DEBUG: suspended generator _run_to_list(query.py:979) returned [Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 1), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 20, 39, 37, 659460))]  
root: DEBUG: all_pending: success: remove <Future 106a2e650 created by fetch_async(query.py:1223) for tasklet _run_to_list(query.py:971); result [Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 1), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 20, 39, 37, 659460))]>  
root: DEBUG: nowevent: _on_future_completion  
root: DEBUG: <Future 1069e9ad0 created by get_async(query.py:1245) for tasklet _get_async(query.py:1247); pending> is no longer blocked waiting for <Future 106a2e650 created by fetch_async(query.py:1223) for tasklet _run_to_list(query.py:971); result [Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 1), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 20, 39, 37, 659460))]>  
root: DEBUG: Sending [Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 1), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 20, 39, 37, 659460))] to suspended generator _get_async(query.py:1250)  
root: DEBUG: suspended generator _get_async(query.py:1250) returned Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 1), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 20, 39, 37, 659460))  
root: DEBUG: all_pending: success: remove <Future 1069e9ad0 created by get_async(query.py:1245) for tasklet _get_async(query.py:1247); result Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 1), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 20, 39, 37, 659460))>  
root: DEBUG: all_pending: add <Future 1069cf8d0 created by fetch_async(query.py:1223) for tasklet _run_to_list(query.py:971); pending>  
root: DEBUG: nowevent: _help_tasklet_along  
root: DEBUG: Sending None to initial generator _run_to_list(query.py:971)  
root: DEBUG: initial generator _run_to_list(query.py:971) yielded <google.appengine.api.apiproxy_stub_map.UserRPC object at 0x106a2edd0>  
root: DEBUG: rpc: datastore_v3.RunQuery  
root: DEBUG: Sending <google.appengine.datastore.datastore_query.Batch object at 0x106a2ef10> to suspended generator _run_to_list(query.py:979)  
root: DEBUG: suspended generator _run_to_list(query.py:979) returned [Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 1), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 20, 39, 37, 659460)), Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 1001), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 20, 39, 43, 164283)), Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 2001), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 20, 44, 59, 425351)), Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 3001), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 20, 45, 39, 127541)), Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 4001), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 20, 46, 40, 884853)), Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 5001), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 21, 10, 45, 14308)), Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 6001), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 21, 56, 12, 419565)), Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 7001), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 22, 0, 14, 800335)), Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 8001), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 22, 1, 7, 931768)), Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 9001), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 21, 13, 34, 43, 876008))]  
root: DEBUG: all_pending: success: remove <Future 1069cf8d0 created by fetch_async(query.py:1223) for tasklet _run_to_list(query.py:971); result [Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 1), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 20, 39, 37, 659460)), Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 1001), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 20, 39, 43, 164283)), Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 2001), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 20, 44, 59, 425351)), Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 3001), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 20, 45, 39, 127541)), Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 4001), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 20, 46, 40, 884853)), Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 5001), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 21, 10, 45, 14308)), Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 6001), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 21, 56, 12, 419565)), Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 7001), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 22, 0, 14, 800335)), Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 8001), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 18, 22, 1, 7, 931768)), Greeting(key=Key('Greeting', 9001), author=Author(email=u'elonMusk@example.com', identity=u'888'), content=u'Test Value', date=datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 21, 13, 34, 43, 876008))]>  
--------------------- >> end captured logging << ---------------------  

----------------------------------------------------------------------  
Ran 2 tests in 0.835s  

FAILED (failures=1)
```

#

EDIT towards resolution:
The teardown() was being called, the output from the print was being swallowed by nosetests.
The --nocapture flag stops this behavior.

The persistence of the datastore entities in the failed tests stems from the fact that testbed.deactivate() seems to only flush the in-memory datastore and not data stored in a file on the hard drive.
I had defined 'datastore_file' with the path to a sqlite3 database which seems to maintain state despite testbed.deactivate()

Comment: was there any exception in setup?. teardown in called only if setup succeeds

Comment: I've looked for exceptions. If they are happening, they aren't being logged as I included all the output above.
I also have tried placing print statements in the setup and they are logged, so I think the setup is running without problems. How could I get more granular?

Comment: Your test failed at `test_guest_can_submit_new_greeting_and_author` right? I haven't been on Python tests for a while but would `tearDown` as a class-level method be called if the test fails before the exiting the class?

Comment: The tearDown() should be called everytime if the setUp() succeeds. The setup seems to succeed.

Comment: Could you try writing to a file as part of the tearDown() method and let us know if that works? (would help distinguish between the expected print output not appearing and tearDown() not being called)

Comment: Apart from the print statements, how do you know that tearDown is not being called?

Comment: The greetings query iterates +1 entity each time I run the test. self.testbed.deactivate() should flush the saved entities on teardown()

Comment: I put a print statement to show the service names as they were called to be deactivated: deactivate: user
deactivate: memcache
deactivate: datastore_v4
deactivate: datastore_v3

Comment: I'm still not sure why the datastore isn't being flushed.

Comment: Glad you made progress @BryanWheelock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tearDown method is being called, but nosetests is swallowing the output.

Here's a minimal example.

```
import unittest


class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def tearDown(self):
        print 'Calling tearDown'

    def test_1(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

    def test_2(self):
        self.assertTrue(False)
```

Called with the standard library unittest test runner, output from the print statement is shown for each test:

```
$ python -m unittest tests
Calling tearDown
.FCalling tearDown

======================================================================
FAIL: test_2 (tests.MyTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 16, in test_2
    self.assertTrue(False)
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Called with nosetests, the output is not shown:

```
$ nosetests -v  --with-gae --gae-lib-root=$APPENGINE
test_1 (tests.MyTestCase) ... ok
test_2 (tests.MyTestCase) ... FAIL

======================================================================
FAIL: test_2 (tests.MyTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kev/python_projects/usr/local/bin/python2.7/tests.py", line 16, in test_2
    self.assertTrue(False)
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.268s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

If we pass the --nocapture flag to nosetests the output from the print statement is displayed:

```
$ nosetests -v --nocapture --with-gae --gae-lib-root=$APPENGINE
test_1 (tests.MyTestCase) ... Calling tearDown
ok
test_2 (tests.MyTestCase) ... FAIL
Calling tearDown

======================================================================
FAIL: test_2 (tests.MyTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kev/python_projects/usr/local/bin/python2.7/tests.py", line 16, in test_2
    self.assertTrue(False)
AssertionError: False is not true

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.265s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

The --nocapture option is described at http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/capture.html

Comment: --no-capture does reveal the print statements that were previously hidden. 
Looks like teardown() is called, but for whatever reason is not flushing the database.

Comment: @BryanWheelock I can't say for certain, but it looks like your code is a mixture of the 'unittest' approach to testing described in the GAE docs and the description in the Nosegae docs, where there are no calls to setUp/tearDown.  If you want to stick with  nosegae I'd suggest looking at http://pythonhosted.org/NoseGAE/#configuring-the-testbed and following their example code more closely.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I've had a hard time finding any example code outside the documentation https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs

Answer (score 2):

Code present does not match with output. According to output, failed test is test_guest_can_submit_new_greeting_and_author, and failure is following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
      File "/Users/Bryan/work/GoogleAppEngine/guestbook/functional_tests.py", line 124, in test_guest_can_submit_new_greeting_and_author  
        self.assertEqual(1, len(Greeting.query().fetch(10)))  
    AssertionError: 1 != 10
```

But test_guest_can_submit_new_greeting_and_author doesn't contain shown assertion:

```
def test_guest_can_submit_new_greeting_and_author(self):  

     #self.browser.get('http://localhost:8080')  
     self.loginUser()  
     greetings = Greeting.query(Greeting.author.email=='elonMusk@example.com').get()  
     pprint.pprint(greetings)  
     assert(Greeting.query(Greeting.author.email=='elonMusk@example.com').get())
```

Looks like you execute different version of file with tests.

Comment: Good eye. I had a bunch of comments on my code that I deleted and I accidentally deleted:  self.assertEqual(1, len(Greeting.query().fetch(10)))